# Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]:

Tags: php, sql

I have this problem

> Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: (42000/1064): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, keyword)
>   VALUES (?,?,?,?)' at line 1 in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\Optimizer\login\submit.php on line 125

I have this problem while making link directory using this code:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT url (url, title, desc, keyword) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"))**==>>Line 125**
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $input['url'], $input['title'],$input['desc'],$input['keyword']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

At least `desc` is a reserved keyword, possibly some more of your field names. Put backticks around the field names that are reserved keywords.